# Formating data on Datatable returns data with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a table which I couldnt export to excel with formatted numbers, because they get messed up on excel.  What I did, was to clean the number so it just returned a number withouth symbol, commas, or dots. This fix the issue now I can modified the numbers and apply operations to them in excel.  The problem now its on the other columns it showing full html instead of just the text. I made a code to clean html tags on the data, but it still showing some html entities, I just want it to show clear text.

```
  {
  extend: 'excel',
  exportOptions: {
      columns: ':visible',
      format: {
          body: function(data, row, column, node) {               
                 return column >= 7 && column <= 9 ? data.replace( /[$,.]/g, '' ) : data;

          }
      }
  }
```

[image]

When I apply strip tags code, the html tags disappears but I still have html code left. I wonder if there is a function to just display data text, since without formatting, it just display text normally without any html.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to get the innerText of the node